# VXLAN over Wireguard with VLAN-VNI mapping

Tags: vpn, vxlan

I am currently attempting to setup a L2 bridge between two sites using VXLAN to provide the L2 connectivity and Wireguard as transport/L3, eventually with plans to expand it multiple sites.
I've previously done a Layer 2 bridge between two sites using GRE over Wireguard and it's been rock-solid, but I'm trying to better understand VXLAN now, and am looking to replace the GRE with VXLAN.

I've been trying to make use of the info both [here](https://legacy.netdevconf.info/2.2/slides/prabhu-linuxbridge-tutorial.pdf) and [here](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-vxlan-bgp-evpn) but for the life of me I can't get traffic to pass over the bridge between sites.

I have two Debian machines with bridge-utils installed. They're also running nftables with rules to drop all DHCP traffic as when I first setup the GRE tunnel I ended up with machines getting assigned IPs from the remote network...

Host A is setup with:

```
Wireguard wg0 - 172.30.100.1/24
Bridge br0 - 10.0.0.160/24
```

Host B is setup with:

```
Wireguard wg0 - 172.30.100.2/24
Bridge br0 - 10.1.0.160/24
```

The `AllowedIPs` on the Wireguard configs is only for the Wireguard subnet 172.30.100.0/24. This was working with the GRE config and I'd assume would work with VXLAN too, as the VXLAN traffic is encapsulated within the Wireguard tunnel.

The bridges both have port `ens18`, `vlan-aware yes` and `bridge-vids 1-4096` in `/etc/network/interfaces`

I have a script based on the 'Recipe 2' from the first link I posted above, i.e. a single tunnel with multiple VNIs. The script adds the VXLAN interface vx0 to br0, which waits until after wg0 is up, and loops to do the VLAN/VNI mapping:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Gets Wireguard interface IP address.
wgip=`ip a s wg0 | egrep -o 'inet [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | cut -d' ' -f2`

ip link add vx0 type vxlan dstport 4789 external local $wgip dev wg0 # Creates vxlan with wg0 IP as local
#Here is where I may be going wrong but I've tried various combinations ^^^

sleep 1
ip link set dev vx0 master br0 # Adds vxlan to bridge
bridge link set dev vx0 vlan_tunnel on # Enables vlan tunnel on vxlan

# Maps each VLAN to VNIs across the tunnel.
for vlan in 10 20 30; do
        bridge vlan add vid $vlan dev vx0
        bridge vlan add vid $vlan dev ens18
        bridge vlan add dev vx0 vid $vlan tunnel_info id $vlan

# Think I can remove the below line once BGP is working as BGP will provide the learning??
bridge fdb append 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev vx0 vni $vlan dst 10.1.0.160

done

ip link set dev vx0 up
```

I may be completely on the wrong track here, and it might just be down to routing. But if there's anything that looks off in the above, any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: VXLAN creates  VLAN-enabled L2.tunneling links *over an IP/L3 network*. Accordingly, if there's already an L2 tunnel over VPN then you don't really need VXLAN. However, using primarily L3 VPN links with VXLAN to create L2 connectivity where required might be what you're really after, but that's not clear from your question.

Comment: That's right, the L2 connectivity over L3 VPN is what I'm trying to achieve. I've got it working with GRE over Wireguard already but I'd like to completely replace this with VXLAN over Wireguard

Comment: Added a little bit of clarification to the original post :)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Comment: Setup your WG "mesh". Then setup the VXLAN VTEP's to use the protected links to reach each other. At that point, it's just simple routing.